# Random 503 errors from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Not sure if i should post here or on Serverfault but this morning we have been getting random 503 errors from Azure (web apps).

They occur from random places across the world and i do get them myself from time to time.

In our "Support Observe" view i do see a lot of errors:

[image]

I do not see that amount of erros in our event logs thou. I do however see some errors that could be something like.

*6136
w3wp
Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024891*

and from W3SVC-WP that are really cryptic like.

*1

5

50000780*

I've found some other posts about these kind of errors here and they seems to point towards issue with Azure sometimes and sometimes not.

I'm on the East US datacenter. Anyone else having issues or can help me figuring out what this is. The fact that is occuring randomly across the world really do point towards an Azure issue?

I could also add that i do not do any load balancing so it could not be that one of the instances is down and or something like that. I have restarted and redeployed the code and so on as well.

Comment: Did you find anything interesting?